# iTunes will not connect with Yamaha AV Reciever icon

Tags: itunes, airplay

I have just purchased a new Yamaha AV Receiver RX-V675 which is AirPlay capable.  I have everything installed and configured as per directions in the Yamaha manual and according to Windows & and iTunes directions. The iTunes AirPlay icon shows the receiver (with a speaker icon).  However when I click to initiate the Yamaha it will not execute nor will a check mark show up.   Everything seems set up correctly as far as I know.  I am looking for help and a solution.  I have updated my firmware on the Yamaha and set up with the following equipment configuration:

- Dell Studio XPS
- Windows 7
- Yamaha is on a hard wired network connection
- iTunes 10.2.2.14
- Windows 7 set up for HomeGroup network and sharing
- Router  - Netgear WGR614v9

Problem is that the Yamaha AirPlay icon in iTunes will not click on.